# React Bootstrap NavDropdown link overriding NavDropdown.Item link

Tags: reactjs, navbar, react-router-dom, react-bootstrap

We have a  on our React application, and we are attempting to nest several `<NavDropdown.Item />` within a `<NavDropdown />`.

[image]

In the screenshot above, clicking **Tools** routes to `/tools`, and clicking the dropdown options *should* link to `/tools/shot-charts`, `/tools/team-stats-graphs`, etc. You can see this in the code below:

```
import { Nav, Navbar, NavDropdown } from 'react-bootstrap';

<Navbar.Collapse id='basic-navbar-nav'>
    <div className='navbar-nav-wrapper'>
        <Nav>
            <NavDropdown
                title='Tools'
                as={Link}
                to='/tools'
                className={`${isTools ? 'selected' : ''}`}
                onMouseEnter={() => setIsToolsHovered(true)}
                onMouseLeave={() => setIsToolsHovered(false)}
                onClick={() => history.push('/tools')}
                show={isToolsHovered}
            >
                <NavDropdown.Item as={Link} to={'/tools/shot-charts'}>Shot Charts</NavDropdown.Item>
                <NavDropdown.Item as={Link} to={'/tools/team-scatter'}>Team Stats Graphs</NavDropdown.Item>
                <NavDropdown.Item as={Link} to={'/tools/player-scatter'}>Player Stats Graphs</NavDropdown.Item>
                <NavDropdown.Item as={Link} to={'/tools/model-fitting'}>Linear Regressions</NavDropdown.Item>
            </NavDropdown>
        </Nav>
    </div>
</Navbar.Collapse>
```

Currently when `Shot Charts` is clicked, the page renders twice, first with the `/tools/shot-charts` url and then immediately after to the `/tools` url. This is problem. It appears that `onClick={() => history.push('/tools')}` on the `<NavDropdown />` is triggering even though **Shot Charts** is clicked rather than **Tools**.

If we remove `onClick={() => history.push('/tools')}`, then the 4 dropdown buttons work, however clicking on **Tools** then does not change the page. It looks like `as={Link}` and `to='/tools'` on the `<NavDropdown />` aren't doing anything to make **Tools** clickable.

Is there anyway for the  and the <NavDropdown.Item /.'s to be separate links as is described & coded above?

Answer (score 1):

I don't think there should be a link `to` prop ***and*** an `onClick` to effectively do the same thing on the outer `NavDropdown`, but the issue is likely that the `onClick` event from the nested `NavDropdown.Item` `Link`s is propagating up to the `NavDropdown`.

I suggest removing the `onClick` handler on `NavDropdown`, and adding an `onClick` handler to the nested `NavDropdown.Item` components to stop the propagation of the click event.

```
const stopClickPropagation = event => event.stopPropagation();

...

<NavDropdown
  title='Tools'
  as={Link}
  to='/tools'
  className={`${isTools ? 'selected' : ''}`}
  onMouseEnter={() => setIsToolsHovered(true)}
  onMouseLeave={() => setIsToolsHovered(false)}
  show={isToolsHovered}
>
  <NavDropdown.Item
    as={Link}
    to={'/tools/shot-charts'}
    onClick={stopClickPropagation}
  >
    Shot Charts
  </NavDropdown.Item>
  <NavDropdown.Item
    as={Link}
    to={'/tools/team-scatter'}
    onClick={stopClickPropagation}
  >
    Team Stats Graphs
  </NavDropdown.Item>
  <NavDropdown.Item
    as={Link}
    to={'/tools/player-scatter'}
    onClick={stopClickPropagation}
  >
    Player Stats Graphs
  </NavDropdown.Item>
  <NavDropdown.Item
    as={Link}
    to={'/tools/model-fitting'}
    onClick={stopClickPropagation}
  >
    Linear Regressions
  </NavDropdown.Item>
</NavDropdown>
```